# overflow:scroll stops hover states from activating

Tags: css, list, scroll, height, overflow

link to [codepen](http://codepen.io/mkov88/pen/249908ec99bd8e7a787733ce5235b22a?editors=1100)

I'm trying to make it so there is a max-height (or height) set to this very long list, and for the rest to scroll. I was able to easily achieve that with

height:800px;
  overflow:scroll;

The Problem I have is that the "#subcategory" items stop displaying on hover when I apply overflow:scroll

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

**Basic HTML Structure**

```
  <!-- Start Auto Transport -->
  <li id="topCategory"><a href="#">Auto Transport</a>
  <ul id="subContainer">
        <li id="subCategory"><a href="#">Auto Insurance</a></li>
        <li id="subCategory"><a href="#">Auto Payment</a></li>
        <li id="subCategory"><a href="#">Gas</a></li>
        <li id="subCategory"><a href="#">Parking</a></li>
        <li id="subCategory"><a href="#">Public Transportation</a></li>
        <li id="subCategory"><a href="#">Service Parts</a></li>
          <!-- add new becomes text field, user enters text then it becomes added as category -->
          <li class="hideNewCategory">
            <a class="mmNewCat" data-number="1" href="#"><i class="icon ion-plus-circled"></i>Add New Category</a>
            <input id="mmCat1" class="mmCatInpt" type="text" placeholder="Enter New Category" maxlength="25"></input>
          </li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <!-- End Auto Transport -->


  <!-- Start Bills Utilities -->
  <li id="topCategory"><a href="#">Bills & Utilities</a>
    <ul id="subContainer">
        <li id="subCategory"><a href="#">Domain Names</a></li>
        <li id="subCategory"><a href="#">Fraud Protection</a></li>
        <li id="subCategory"><a href="#">Home Phone</a></li>
        <li id="subCategory"><a href="#">Hosting</a></li>
        <li id="subCategory"><a href="#">Mobile Phone</a></li>
        <li id="subCategory"><a href="#">Television</a></li>
        <li id="subCategory"><a href="#">Utilities</a></li>
        <!-- add new becomes text field, user enters text then it becomes added as category -->
          <li class="hideNewCategory">
            <a class="mmNewCat" data-number="2" href="#"><i class="icon ion-plus-circled"></i>Add New Category</a>
            <input id="mmCat2" class="mmCatInpt" type="text" placeholder="Enter New Category" maxlength="25"></input>
          </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <!-- End Bills Utilities -->
```

**relevant CSS**

```
ul li:hover #topContainer{
  display: block;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: $blue;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#topContainer{
  list-style: none;
  color: $blue;
  width: 260px;
  height: auto;
  background: $white;
  opacity: 0.9;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  height:800px;
  overflow:scroll;
}

#topCategory {
  float: none;
  width: auto;
  height: 20px;
    text-align: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

#topCategory a:hover {
  color: $white;
  background-color: $blue;
}

#topCategory:hover #subContainer {
  display: block;
}

#topCategory a {
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 41px;
  margin-top: 46px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 20px;
  border-bottom:1px solid $grey-10;
}

#topCategory a:hover {
  color: $white;
}

#subContainer {
  list-style: none;
  color: $blue;
  display: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  min-width: 230px;
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  background: $white;
  opacity: 0.9;
  margin: -107px 0 0 245px;  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

#subContainer a{
  border-bottom:1px solid $grey-10;
  margin-top: 41px;
}

#subCategory {
  float: none;
  width: auto;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#subCategory:hover {
  background: none;
}

.active {
  background: $white;
}

#subCategory {
    float: none;
    // hover length
    width:215px;
    // hover length
    text-align: left;
    height: 25px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: -43px;
}
```

Comment: UPDATE: rofl the hover list items ARE there. you just have to scroll right to see them :/ Totally forgot about overflow-x and overflow-y, however, I've since added  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: visible !important; and it's still behaving the same as just having overflow:scroll

Answer (score 1):

Subcategory should be a  `Class` name not an `Id` element, change that and things will look cleaner.

```
.subcategory {

}

<div class="subcategory"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I changed it and while semantically I agree it shouldn't have repeating IDs the problem and behavior still remain the same. any other ideas? Codepen updated     http://codepen.io/mkov88/pen/249908ec99bd8e7a787733ce5235b22a

Comment: Sorry for not responding earlier. It looks like you already solved your answer, thanks for sharing.

Comment: I didn't solve the issue, only added information about it.

Comment: Contact me on skype @systemconnection or email denilsonjvv@gmail.com